# numpy.array to PNG file and back

Tags: python, numpy, png, python-imaging-library, pypng

I have a 2d `numpy.array` object of `dtype=uint16` representing a grayscale image. How do I save it to a PNG file and then read it back, obtaining the same array?

Comment: Is this what is described in [the pyPng Code Examples](https://pythonhosted.org/pypng/ex.html)?

Comment: I think PNG>np is given, but the other way around only shows a 3d array and I can't figure out how to make it work with a 2d array. Also as I'm starting off with a numpy.array, I need that example first to try it out. in short, it isn't trivial from the examples...

Answer (score 4):

scikit-image makes this pretty easy:

```
from skimage.io import imread, imsave
import numpy as np

x = np.ones((100, 100), dtype=np.uint16)
imsave('test.png', x)
y = imread('test.png')
(x == y).all()  # True
```

Comment: But this has a drawback of accessing disk and back. Can it be done in memory?